# When is a linear transformation of random vector unique

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-matrices

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector with distribution $F_X$.

Now let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix and define 
\begin{align}
Z= AX,
\end{align}
with distribution $Z\sim F_Z$.

**My question:**

Can we show sufficient and necessary conditions on matrix $A$ under which   $F_X$ is unique for every $F_Z$.

Clear, it is sufficient that $A$ is left invertible, that is there exists a matrix $C$ such that $CA=I$.  Is this also, necessary?

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, choose some vector $v\ne0$ such that $Av=0$ and some random vector $X$ such that $AX$ has the desired distribution, then every $X+Yv$ with $Y$ real valued is such $A(X+Yv)=AX$ hence $A(X+Yv)$ also has the desired distribution but $X+Yv$ may not have the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: @Did  Thanks. A lot for this very insightful example.